# C++ Tool to check each header has an implementation

Tags: java, c++, header, java-native-interface, implementation

I'm working on a project mixing Java and C++ code. I use JNI for the communication between them. I have java files where I declare the headers of the C++ methods callable from Java side. With JNI, the corresponding C++ headers are generated automatically.

Now, the problem is I'd like to use a tool to check all the generated C++ headers have an implementation, because the Java developer and the C++ developer are two different persons in my team, and it causes some runtime exception when an unimplemented C++ method is called.

Does such a tool exist ?

The more specific question could be : How to force compiler to show errors when finding an unimplemented JNI method in C++ side ?

Comment: About the tool: I am not aware of any tool, but I think a tool like this would render some desired C++ functionality as error. Such as a non-copyable idiom (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/noncopyable.hpp).

Off-topic: About the run-time exception: That's strange. At the linking phase you should get a warning about the unimplemented methods. The only situation I have got a c++ run time exception (related to missing functions) was when I have called a pure virtual method from a constructor... Evil, evil...

Comment: @fritzone: you won't get linker errors link that for shared libraries, which is what JNI uses.